# Cannot pull or clone from Bonobo Git Server

Tags: git, bonobo

I'm trying to use Bonobo git server to store my own projects. However, I'm running into trouble cloning, pulling from, and pushing to the repository.

Whenever I try to perform an action (either http or https; clone, pull or push) I get the following:

fatal: unable to access 'http://user:password@my.noip.com:1234/Bonobo.Git.Server/Repository.git/': Failed connect to my.noip.com:1234; No error

Background:

1) I'm using no-ip to get external access to my setup.

2) I've configured my router to forward requests for two given ports to http (80) and https (443) on my device hosting the Bonobo repository.

3) If I go to my.noip.site:myport/Bonobo.Git.Server in my browser, (both http and https, with respective ports), I can successfully reach the server, login, and edit the repositories (I can even download them).

4) I'm using git version 1.9.5.mysysgit.0

5) I'm using Bonobo Git Server version 3.5.0.0 and Windows 8

6) I was able to successfully push to the repository from the machine hosting the site. I didn't test cloning / pulling because the code was already on that machine.

7) I Have my account set to contributor and administrator.

8) I verified that the Authentication settings were set to Forms Authentication.

**Edit 1**

Turns out, the problem isn't entirely (or at all) Bonobo.

I enabled basic authentication for IIS and followed Bonobo instructions for basic authentication (except I didn't import Windows admin users).

With that, I was able to access the repositories through devices on my WLAN and with a git app on my phone (on cellular network).

Pulls from my pythonanywhere  account fail because they restrict external access for free accounts.

However, I still can't pull from my work computer. I can ping my noip account and get valid responses, but any other request fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally worked out what the problem was. The computers I use at work have separate proxy settings. Some use no proxy, others use a work provided proxy. When using the work provided proxy, machine local addresses don't work (e.g. django development server / localhost fail), but there's better coverage for WAN sites (like my Bonobo site).

In Start > Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings:
I had the proxy setup properly so I was able to access my site via browser. I had just assumed these were global settings... they were not.

So, the following steps resolved my issues (these are steps I had to take AFTER completing Bonobo Installation Steps):

1. Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > Internet Information Services > Security > Basic Authentication [Enabled]
2. Follow instructions for enabling Bonobo Basic Authentication (with the exception that I did not import windows admins).
3. Verify the page is reachable via WAN (Wide Area Network).
4. Verify proxy settings and use them with git.

There are a couple options to change git proxy settings, but this was my method:

- `git init /path/to/repo`
- Navigate to the repository
- `git config http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypassword@proxy.com:proxyport`
- `git config https.proxy https://proxyuser:proxypassword@proxy.con:proxyport`

It's also worthwhile to note that your proxy (like mine) may not require a username or password. In this case, just exclude `proxyuser:proxyoassword@`.